# Proving $\lim _{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{x}=-\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I calculate the limit:

$$\lim _{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{x}$$

The answer is clearly $-\infty$, but how do I prove it? Its clear that as x approaches 0 from the right side, $x$, becomes infinitely small, but negative, making the limit go to $-\infty$, but how do I prove this mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice $\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}$ is strictly decreasing on $(-1,0)$.

I claim that fo any positive integer $n$, if we choose $x$ close enough to $0$$, \displaystyle\frac{1}{x} < -n$. Hint: consider $x\in (-\frac{1}{n},0)$.

Do you see why it should follow that the limit is $-\infty$?

Comment: Wow, that helped a lot, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not familiar with $\epsilon - \delta$ proofs, you can take numbers $x$ such that $x<0$ to show that $x \rightarrow -\infty$.

ex: $1 \div -.0001 = -10000$. Keep dividing by smaller negative numbers to show that $x \rightarrow -\infty$.

Comment: I was looking for something more rigorous. Is there a rigorous way to prove it without delta echelon limits?

Answer (score 1):

Hint, to show $\forall a \lt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0 \text{ such that, } -\delta \lt x \lt 0,~~\frac{1}{x} \lt a$

> $$\text{Let }\delta = -\frac{1}{a}$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Delta Epsilon limits. Are there any other ways to calculate it?

Comment: If you want to prove it rigorously, you must apply delta epsilon approach. But it will be easy to understand this proof if you can look at the graph and it obviously shows that the value of $\frac{1}{x}$ goes to $-\infty$ as $x$ approach $0$ from the left side. The delta epsilon here shows that no matter how small an negative "a" you pick, I can alway find a value of $\frac{1}{x}$, which is smaller than it.

Answer (score 1):

show x = -.0001 then x = -.00000001 then x = -.00000000000000001. Choose values that get closer and closer to 0 then graph that. That is the best way I could show it. Is this what you mean? Or am I making this too simple?

Comment: That's a great way to get a good guess on the limit, but its not rigorous :)

Comment: then the Delta Epsilon way is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

If we say 
$$
\lim_{y \to x} f(y) = f(x)
$$

Then, for 'x' approaching 0 from negative side,

$$
\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{x} = \lim_{-\frac{1}{n} \to 0^-} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}}= -\lim_{-\frac{1}{n} \to 0^-}n = -\infty
$$