# Proving that $3/(4*(x-2))$ is bounded

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

As the title says I want to prove that $3/(4*(x-2))$ is bounded I kind of have a rough idea. If we take a limit as $x$ approaches $2$ from the right side it goes to $+\infty$... but is it a mathematically rigorous proof? Or is it even the right intuition?

The domain of a function is $(2;+\infty)$

Comment: Bounded on which domain (i.e. where does $x$ live)? For instance the function is bounded on [0,1] but is unbounded on [0,2[

Comment: Sorry yeah i know i just added domain of a function

Comment: The function is not defined in $x=2$ so the domain could not be $[2,\infty)$, if you meant $(2,\infty)$ then the function is defined there but not bounded.

Comment: Yes so on interval (2;+ i nf) it is not bounded but why exactly?

Comment: Can you find an $x$ value close to (*but not equal to*) $2$ such that your function is bigger than $1000$?  How about so that it is bigger than $1000000$?  How about so that it is bigger than $10000000000000$?   Yes to all?  How about finding an $x$ close to $2$ written in terms of $M$ so that it is bigger than $M$ for whatever $M$ happens to be?

Comment: Yeah i got that but i need mathematically rigorous proof

Comment: How can I write x in terms of M thats my problem

Comment: Just solve it like normal equation?

Comment: @Zura: 'Just solve it like normal equation? ' Yes

Comment: This is an abstract duplicate of [Question 563501](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563501/proving-lim-x-to-0-frac1x-infty?rq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show it is unbounded, you can for each bound $A>0$ explicitly choose an $x\in (2,\infty)$ whose image is not bounded by $A$ (i.e. not in $[-A,A]$, i.e. such that $|\frac{3}{4\cdot (x-2)}|>A$).

To satisfy yourself that this indeed proves what you want, you can write down the definition of a bounded function, then negate it.

Comment: Could you please tell me why did you use absolute value and what it does have to do with A? I mean you defined it but don't see any use of it... Sry for lame questions I am a freshman ...

Comment: Apologies for the $A$, there was a typo... The absolute value is because *unbounded* means: can get arbitrary close to $+\infty$ and/or arbitrarily close to $-\infty$. Since the function is positive on this domain, you don't really need the absolute values here.

Comment: Yeah but that looks like a definition of unbounded function and not like a proof. I mean I know that if i plug xs close to 2 it is going to increase but is it that simple or am i missing something?

Comment: @Zura Take $x=2+\frac{1}{2A}$, then $\frac{3}{4(x-2)}=\frac{6A}{4}>A$.

Comment: 'If I plug xs close to 2 it is going to increase'. You are still missing an argument here, namely that it will continue to increase to infinity (if, no matter how close to $2$ by above you got you were to never go over $5$, then the function would be bounded). You can if you want show that the limit in $2^+$ is indeed $+\infty$ by usual theorems for instance (sum, inversion, composition of limits...) but it's a stronger result (in the sense that it implies that the function is unbounded, but a function could be unbounded without having a defined limit).

Comment: Okey I get it know thanks guys